Ubuntu Server - Restricting ssh access to one IP address
I have a VPS in a datacentre in France. I upload files from my base in Ireland using mobile phone Internet.
My IP seems to be the same from my end. I don't use a proxy but don't know if my mobile Internet provider does or not.
I have done tried to use ufw to restrict ssh access to my server to one single IP address, i.e. that of my home PC.
Here is my code:
$ sudo ufw allow 80

$ sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 to any port 22 proto tcp

$ sudo ufw enable

The trouble is that when I exit the server and try to log back in again, I get blocked.
$ sudo ssh -p 22 myserver@xxx.www.yyy.zzz
ssh: connect to host xxx.www.yyy.zzz port 22: Connection timed out

Should I instead enable ssh within ufw first and then restrict it to my home IP, i.e.
$ sudo ufw allow 80

$ sudo ufw allow ssh

$ sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 to any port 22 proto tcp

$ sudo ufw enable

The various online guides and Ubuntu Bible say nothing of this prior enabling of ssh. I myself read the dedication of port 22 to ssh connections to imply an allowance of ssh when the port was opened . . . but I guess I assumed wrong.
EDIT
I reconfigured ufw to simply allow SSH access from any IP:
  sudo ufw allow ssh

Now all works well, e.g. network connection, SFTP snd so on. Yet it would be nice to restrict IPs allowed access to those of the base PC plus one or two other locations, e.g. a mobile device and a home workstation.

Is the server on the same LAN as your home PC? If not, is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx the public IP of your home PC, or its private LAN IP? Why are you adding the CIDR range /24 if you want to allow a single address?

@steeldriver  Because that's what the Ubuntu Bible does.

Are the server and home PC both at home, in the same network? Is the IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx a public or private address? Does it start with 192.168.xxx.xxx? Have you enabled port forwarding in your router? Add these information in your question.

No it was a commercial VPS inside some datacentre in another EU country. Yes to the IP question. Told not to put it on the web due to some RFC or other and complied. I didn't actively do any settings for port forwarding. I don't know if this is already done (e.g. in the phone factory) or even doable for mobile internet.

Edit your question and add information about: 1. Where your Ubuntu server is, 2. Where the computer you are trying to ssh from is, 3. Does your home computer have a static or dynamic IP address? Indicate in your question that you are using a mobile internet. Internet service provided by mobile companies are more restrictive.

You don't need the sudo ufw allow ssh line. For a single IP address you don't need the /24 in the end. You should not use sudo ssh. since you are using the default port 22, you don't need -p 22. Just ssh myserver@xxx.www.yyy.zzz should be sufficient.

I think xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx may be incorrect, or it may change over time if it is dynamically (not static) your mobile internet service provider.

Edits to OP done.
